# Add permissions to access /media/External drive

Tags: raspbian, permissions

I'm using RaspberryPi and `Raspbian` distribution. Additionally I have installed `Kodi` and set it up to auto start.

I have problems with setting permission to /media/myDrive directory.

It's because od `Kodi` automount. It mounts drives automatically, and I cannot disable/edit it (or there is a way?)

Here's my `/proc/mounts` entry for my drive:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/External fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

I would like to add permissions for user

```
uid=1001(rtorrent) gid=1001(rtorrent) groups=1001(rtorrent),1000(pi)
```

to access this `/media/External`

How can I do this?

P.S. `ls -la` entry for this drive looks like:

```
drwx------   1 pi   pi    8192 Oct 18 13:49 External
```

Answer (score 1):

just add user you want to give permission, in group of user which has permission on drive.

You can find how to add user in existing group. [Add user in existing group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/add-user-to-existing-group)